# Content Type Hub Syndication and lookup site column within a content type 

Tags: content-type, lookup-column

I am a content type which has to have a lookup field.

I have created two exactly identical lists in hub site collection and the consumer site. Then I created the lookup site column and added to the content type in the hub. Unfortunately, syndication failes with the following message:

> Unable to find a lookup list /spikes/consumer/Lists/LanguagesList. The list is not part of the exported package and does not exist in the destination site collection.

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Many Thanks,
Gido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is how I did based on http://ken-sharedpoints.blogspot.com/2010/06/content-type-hub-sync-lookup-lists.html?showComment=1296122223860#c3793669839818038356:

1. published the content type (this is the
   content type which will keep the
   reference data)
2. Created the list in hub and associated it
   with the content type
3. Saved it as a list templated
4. Exported the list template from hub
5. Added the listtemplate.stp into list templates gallery in the subscriber site.
6. Created a list based in the imported list templated
7. Published the content types that have the lookup columns.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case. If I create a lookup column it is targeting a field in a list based on the GUID. Having a new list, created from template or not, it has a unique GUID and the lookup doesn't work. Could you share your method of implementation in more detail please?

Answer (score 2):

The Lookup column has a ListID property which contains the GUID associated with the list it is looking up to, so the ID of the list being lookup to on subscribing site collections must use this ID.

Best way to do this is either create this list through code using CAML, or to template the list from the Hub, and use this template to create the list on all subscribing site collections.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your published site column isn't looking up the list in the different site collection (which you've probably already figured out).

You may have a list that looks the same but unless you deployed a listinstance sharing the same guid it probably won't work.

In SP2010 you're better off addressing this requirement with Managed Metadata although there are probably reasons why this approach is invalid for your situation.

Comment: Niel, Thanks for the reply. Ken in his post [http://ken-sharedpoints.blogspot.com/2010/06/content-type-hub-sync-lookup-lists.html] has mentioned that thsi approach has worked for him